# VSCode: find and replace, but open edited files without saving them

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I perform a find and replace across all files, edits are made, the files are saved, but they are not opened.

Can I configure vscode to open those files that it edited, and not save them until I press <kbd>ctrl+shift+s</kbd>? I seem to remember it working that way once.